# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'add_student'

Tags: python

I am trying to run the program in python, it is not working.

These are the errors I am getting

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 64, in 
File "", line 14, in main -
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'add_student'

> 

where I am getting wrong?

Comment: You defined `roster = []`. Why would you expect the list `roster` to have a method `add_student`? `add_student` is a method of the class `Student`. BTW, the design of the class `Student` seems to be wrong.

Comment: @Matthias how should I do it?

Comment: Should `Student` represent one student or a list of students? You try to use this class for both. It's up to you to decide how you want to fix that. And why those getter methods and attribute names with leading double underscores? That's not what is called "pythonic" code. If you believe that a leading double underscore will make the attribute private: It doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

There are many issues in the code.

- List does not have any `add_student` attribute. Instead you should do `roster.append`
- If you analyze your code design you should not mix the code for a single student and roster.

1 simple way to overcome this issue is this

```
def display_students(students):
    for student in students:
        print(student)
            
def main():
    roster = []
    roster.append(Student("47899", "Susan", "Meyers" , "Accounting"))
    roster.append(Student("39119", "Mark", "Jones" , "Programming"))
    roster.append(Student("81774", "Joy", "Rogers", "Engineering"))
    display_students(roster)

    
class Student:
    
    def __init__(self, student_id, first_name, last_name, student_major):
        self.__student_id = student_id
        self.__first_name = first_name
        self.__last_name = last_name
        self.__student_major = student_major

    def get_student_id(self):
        return self.__student_id

    def get_first_name(self):
        return self.__first_name
    
    def get_last_name(self):
        return self.__last_name

    def get_student_major(self):
        return self.__student_major

    def __str__(self):
        return "# {} {}  {} {}".format(self.__student_id, self.__first_name, self.__last_name, self.__student_major)

 

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```